# Tomcat Blocks and Not Responding

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-unit, junitperf

I have a tomcat server and I'm running Performance Test with junitperf against it.

I create 20 simultaneous requests each time.

OK, here's the problem: sometimes, it returns really fast, all 20 requests are responded within 3 seconds; but at the other times, it seems to block forever and never finished (in fact, about 18, 19 of these requests will finish, but the rest 1 or 2 just got blocked forever)

Here's how I tried to debug the problem:

At the client side:

```
WebConversation webConversation = new WebConversation();
System.out.println("Before calling " + url);
WebResponse response = webConversation.getResponse(request);
System.err.println("Called " + url);
```

At the server side, at the very first line of the servlet function, I have:

```
logger.debug("Enter Servlet");
```

Now, when it blocks, at the client side I can see 20 "Before calling" and 18,19 "Called ...". At the server side, I also only see 18,19 "Enter Servlet" logs.

So I think the problem is, the client has already sent the requests, but the Tomcat server is not responding to them, the Servlet function is not even called.

Meanwhile, when I checked the log, I found nothing regarding why is it blocked. There's no error information, no exception, nothing.

Can someone help me with this?

Edit#2:

Here's a full thread dump:

```
2015-02-08 11:20:09
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.71-b01 mixed mode):

"http-bio-8080-exec-20" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdf803000 nid=0x7c03 waiting on condition [0x000000011796a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-19" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdf802800 nid=0x7a03 waiting on condition [0x0000000117867000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-18" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdbb0b800 nid=0x7803 waiting on condition [0x0000000117764000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-11" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb845000 nid=0x6a03 waiting on condition [0x000000011704f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-9" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdf05b800 nid=0x6603 waiting on condition [0x0000000116e49000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-8" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdd803000 nid=0x6403 waiting on condition [0x0000000116d46000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-7" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdd801000 nid=0x6203 waiting on condition [0x0000000116c43000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-4" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdf801000 nid=0x3807 waiting on condition [0x0000000115ace000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-3" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdf800000 nid=0x3407 waiting on condition [0x0000000115825000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-exec-1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdd001000 nid=0x4b07 waiting on condition [0x0000000113366000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007bacb8918> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda97d800 nid=0x5703 waiting on condition [0x0000000116a3d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ajp-bio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdaa51800 nid=0x5503 runnable [0x000000011693a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdaaec800 nid=0x5303 waiting on condition [0x0000000116837000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:152)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdab7b000 nid=0x5103 runnable [0x0000000116734000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda994800 nid=0x4f03 waiting on condition [0x000000011627c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb940800 nid=0x4903 in Object.wait() [0x0000000115412000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000701b92758> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x0000000701b92758> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda014000 nid=0x4503 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda00e000 nid=0x4303 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda81c800 nid=0x4103 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facda81b800 nid=0x3f07 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb005800 nid=0x3003 in Object.wait() [0x000000011322a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000701bb32d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000701bb32d0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb005000 nid=0x2e03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000113127000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000701bb2e30> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x0000000701bb2e30> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda806000 nid=0x1903 runnable [0x0000000102398000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:453)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb002000 nid=0x2c03 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda813000 nid=0x1c03 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb800000 nid=0x1e03 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb801000 nid=0x2003 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda00b000 nid=0x2203 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda813800 nid=0x2403 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda814800 nid=0x2603 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb801800 nid=0x2803 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007facdb802000 nid=0x2a03 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007facda01c800 nid=0x4703 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 161

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 289280K, used 132571K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007cdf80000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 264192K, 46% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007b234ee68,0x00000007bac80000)
  from space 25088K, 35% used [0x00000007bac80000,0x00000007bb528120,0x00000007bc500000)
  to   space 25088K, 0% used [0x00000007cc700000,0x00000007cc700000,0x00000007cdf80000)
 ParOldGen       total 174592K, used 29377K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000070aa80000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
  object space 174592K, 16% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000701cb0620,0x000000070aa80000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 17514K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fc300000, 0x0000000700000000)
  object space 21504K, 81% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006fbf1aa00,0x00000006fc300000)
```

Comment: Did you tried to get stack dump?

Comment: I can get the threads dump by kill -3 {pid}. What information should I look for?

Comment: See if any of the thread is in blocked state?

Comment: No, just a lot of "TIMED_WAITING (parking)"

Comment: Cant help without looking at stack trace. So would be good if you paste trace.

Comment: I added the full thread dump. Thanks!

Comment: Heads with same problem!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved if I still different machine to run the client program (I originally used my local machine, which is Mac OS X, then I switched to Fedora). So I guess it's the client's issue. However, the actual reason remains unclear.